# Bad Gateway The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server

Tags: apache-2.4

I am trying to set the webapp using Apache (Server version: Apache/2.4.38 (Unix)) with SSL and Tomcat (Apache Tomcat/8.5.41)

3 tomcat instances are set as str1, str2, str3 with below settings with jvmroute respectively.
Server.xml as:

```
Connector port="8988" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443"              
Connector port="8010" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"
Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="str1"
```

In Httpd.conf with SSL module enabled and pointing httpd-ssl.conf

```
Listen 80
ServerName abcd.example.com:80
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteRule (.*) https://abcd.example.com/search [R=301,L]
```

In httpd-ssl.conf

```
Listen 443
SSLEngine on
ServerName abcd.example.com:443
```

In Proxy-balancer.conf:

```
ProxyPass /search balancer://stcluster/search
ProxyPassReverse /search balancer://stcluster/search
<Proxy balancer://stcluster>
    BalancerMember http://localhost:8988 loadfactor=1 route=str1
    BalancerMember http://localhost:8987 loadfactor=1 route=str2
    BalancerMember http://localhost:8986 loadfactor=1 route=str3
    ProxySet lbmethod=bybusyness
    ProxySet stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid
    ProxySet timeout=300
</Proxy>
```

Comment: What is the problem with your current configuration? What is it you're expecting to happen, what's happening instead, what do the logs say?

Comment: Thanks Jeni for asking. when i am hitting https://abcd.domain.com/search then it receives error as "The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server." . I am unable to locate any problem.

Comment: What happens if you try to connect manually directly to the backend server from your webserver, using telnet or netcat?

Comment: I am not understanding this but i guess you are asking about the DNS resolution and it works. If i hit the http://abcd.domain.com then itworks page comes.

Comment: when hitting 'https://abcd.domain.com/search' then it does recognize the certificate and validates it but throws badgateway error

Comment: I'm not asking about DNS, I'm asking if the backend servers give you a proper response when you connect to them from the apache server.

Comment: Locally yes but not using the SSL.

Comment: I am receiving error in error.log as "AH01097: pass request body failed to 127.0.0.1:8988 (localhost) from "

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to conclude beyond proxy-balancer.conf miss configuration. Not sure what.
I copied the configured Apache/2.4.17 and managed to delete the older apr and finally able to solve the purpose for now.